# C Shell Argument If Else Loop

Tags: csh

I am writing a script that, if one or more arguments are entered after the script, it will display them. if no arguments are entered, it will say "Please enter one or more arguments."

For some reason, my script will do the first, but will not executive 0 argument task in the script. What am I doing wrong? Is it just a logical error?

```
foreach arg ( $* )
        if ( $#arg == 0 ) then
                echo "Please enter one or more arguments."
        else if ( $#arg > 0 ) then
                echo "Found argument = $arg"
        endif
end
```

Comment: Learning CSH is almost never a good idea in this day and age. If you are maintaining CSH scripts then consider porting them to a new language.

Comment: [csh considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). I recommend you learn the ubiquitous [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) instead

Answer (score 1):

If you have no arguments to your script, then it is not going to do anything as $* will equal nothing.

Your script is effectively:

```
foreach arg (  )
   echo "Nothing to see here"
end
```

What would make more sense:

```
# check how many arguments passed to script
if ( $#argv == 0 ) then
     echo "Please enter one or more arguments."
     exit 1
endif

foreach arg ( $* )
    echo "Found argument = $arg"
end
```